# jquery-jtable: how to avoid this field is ambiguous in the db query?

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

I am using jquery jtable and one of my field names is considered ambiguous at the mysql layer.  I was using a str_replace normalizer step so i could add a table namespace there.  but i wonder if there is a better way.

jtable snippet

```
uid: {
 ...
}
```

ajax snippet

```
$sort = str_replace('uid', 'p.uid', $sort);  // this adds the p. table namespace
$query = "select ..... {$sort}";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just found a way to do this without the ajax step.  ends up by putting the field name in quotes i could just add the table namespace directly to the jtable description.

thought it may help someone else...

i changed the jtable code from:

```
uid: {
 ...
}
```

to

```
"p.uid": {
 ...
}
```